# How to get the selected item value from DropDownMenu

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, dropdown

i'm new in flutter, i create my widget GenreDropDown, that shows the various genres of films; i used it in MyHomePage and i would show the selected item in a widget Text (just test), but i don't know how to get the selected item in the MyHomePage screen, i need it because later i would add others widgets TextField and send all data via a FlatButton (like a form)

This is MyHomePage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:appcinema/Model/Genre.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  static const routeName = '/';

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("App Cinema"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Select the genre of the film: ", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17)),
                  GenreDropDown(),

                ],
              ),
              //Text where i would show the selected value of GenreDropDown
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This is the class Genre and GenreDropDown

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Genre{
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Genre(this.id, this.name);

}

class GenreDropDown extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  GenreDropDownWidget createState() => GenreDropDownWidget();
}

class GenreDropDownWidget extends State<GenreDropDown>{

  Genre ddbValue;

  final List<Genre> genreList = <Genre>[
    Genre(1, "Animation"),
    Genre(2, "Action"),
    Genre(3, "Adventure"),
    Genre(4, "Biography"),
    Genre(5, "Comedy"),
    Genre(6, "Crime"),
    Genre(7, "Documentary"),
    Genre(8, "Drama"),
    Genre(9, "Erotic"),
    Genre(10, "Family"),
    Genre(11, "Fantasy"),
    Genre(12, "Horror"),
    Genre(13, "History"),
    Genre(14, "Musical"),
    Genre(15, "Mystery"),
    Genre(16, "Philosophical"),
    Genre(17, "Political"),
    Genre(18, "Romance"),
    Genre(19, "Science Fiction"),
    Genre(20, "Sci-Fi"),
    Genre(21, "Social"),
    Genre(22, "Thriller"),
    Genre(23, "Urban"),
    Genre(24, "War"),
    Genre(25, "Western")
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        DropdownButton<Genre>(
          disabledHint: Text("Disabilitated"),
          hint: Text("ex: Fantasy"),
          isExpanded: false,
          value: ddbValue,
          items: genreList.map<DropdownMenuItem<Genre>>(
                  (Genre item){
                return DropdownMenuItem<Genre>(
                  value: item,
                  child: Text(item.name),
                );
              }
          ).toList(),
          onChanged: (Genre newValue){
            setState(() {
              ddbValue = newValue;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a callback in your Widget to be called on selection change.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  static const routeName = '/';

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Genre ddbValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("App Cinema"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Select the genre of the film: ", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17)),
                  GenreDropDown(onChanged: (Genre newValue) => 
                    setState(() => ddbValue = newValue)
                  )

                ],
              ),
              //Text where i would show the selected value of GenreDropDown
              Text("${ddbValue!=null?ddbValue.name:""}")
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

class Genre{
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Genre(this.id, this.name);

}

class GenreDropDown extends StatefulWidget {

  final Function onChanged;
  GenreDropDown({this.onChanged});

  @override
  GenreDropDownWidget createState() => GenreDropDownWidget();
}

class GenreDropDownWidget extends State<GenreDropDown>{

  final List<Genre> genreList = <Genre>[
    Genre(1, "Animation"),
    Genre(2, "Action"),
    Genre(3, "Adventure"),
    Genre(4, "Biography"),
    Genre(5, "Comedy"),
    Genre(6, "Crime"),
    Genre(7, "Documentary"),
    Genre(8, "Drama"),
    Genre(9, "Erotic"),
    Genre(10, "Family"),
    Genre(11, "Fantasy"),
    Genre(12, "Horror"),
    Genre(13, "History"),
    Genre(14, "Musical"),
    Genre(15, "Mystery"),
    Genre(16, "Philosophical"),
    Genre(17, "Political"),
    Genre(18, "Romance"),
    Genre(19, "Science Fiction"),
    Genre(20, "Sci-Fi"),
    Genre(21, "Social"),
    Genre(22, "Thriller"),
    Genre(23, "Urban"),
    Genre(24, "War"),
    Genre(25, "Western")
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        DropdownButton<Genre>(
          disabledHint: Text("Disabilitated"),
          hint: Text("ex: Fantasy"),
          isExpanded: false,
          items: genreList.map<DropdownMenuItem<Genre>>(
                  (Genre item){
                return DropdownMenuItem<Genre>(
                  value: item,
                  child: Text(item.name),
                );
              }
          ).toList(),
          onChanged: widget.onChanged
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```